# In Tests none of the threads execute the method

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, thread-safety

I got a project, but I see difficulties. https://github.com/siqqQ/ILTasks/tree/master/busThread This is the project(4 files). I am worried about this test
`

```
void areAllPeopleWithDistinctTicket() throws InterruptedException {
    int numberOfPeople = 50;
    TicketManager t = TicketManager.getTicketManager(numberOfPeople);
    Set<Integer> persons = new HashSet<>();
    t.start();

    for (Person person : t.getPersons()) {
        if(!persons.add(person.getTicketNumber()) && person.getTicketNumber()!=null){
            fail("There are people with same tickets");
        }
    }
}
```

When I test it, it shows me in the console that all tickets are SoldOut and none of the people are on the bus.
`

```
Name : Person 1 | Ticket: SoldOut
Name : Person 2 | Ticket: SoldOut
Name : Person 3 | Ticket: SoldOut
Name : Person 4 | Ticket: SoldOut
Name : Person 5 | Ticket: SoldOut
Name : Person 6 | Ticket: SoldOut
Name : Person 7 | Ticket: SoldOut
Name : Person 8 | Ticket: SoldOut
Name : Person 9 | Ticket: SoldOut
Name : Person 10 | Ticket: SoldOut
Name : Person 11 | Ticket: SoldOut
Name : Person 12 | Ticket: SoldOut...
```

`

I will be happy if someone can explain me why is this happening and provide some solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

In `TicketManager`, you're calling `printBusArrangment()` without waiting for the threads to finish executing. Try this:

```
sendAllPeopleToBuyTicket(personsThreads, persons);
for (Thread thread : personThreads) {
    thread.join();
}
printBusArrangment(persons);
```